# How do I count the occurrence of string values based on a condition in a dataframe?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dataframe

I have the following dataframe:

```
        Event_Type Roster_Designation
4          Assist               Male
5            Goal             Female
12         Assist             Female
13           Goal               Male
46           Goal               Male
...           ...                ...
207095       Goal             Female
207108     Assist               Male
207109       Goal               Male
207118     Assist             Female
207119       Goal             Female
```

What I want to know is how many Goals are scored by Females that are Assisted by Males? How many Goals scored by Females are Assisted by Females? and then vice versa (eg. Female assists -> Male goals, male assists - male goals).

Comment: how can you tell which assist related to which goal?

Comment: Sorry, the sequence number is in the left most column. So an assist should be one sequence number lower than the goal sequence number. The data is also arranged sequentially, meaning that any assist should be proceeded by the corresponding goal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import pandas as pd

# test data. expected result is 1 for each category
data = [['Assist', 'Male'], ['Goal', 'Female'], ['Assist', 'Female'], ['Goal', 'Male'], ['Goal', 'Male'], ['Goal', 'Female'], ['Assist', 'Male'], ['Goal', 'Male'], ['Assist', 'Female'], ['Goal', 'Female']]
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['Event_Type', 'Roster_Designation'])

female_female = len(df[(df['Event_Type'] == 'Goal') & (df['Roster_Designation'] == 'Female') & (df['Roster_Designation'].shift() == 'Female') & (df['Event_Type'].shift() == 'Assist')])
female_male = len(df[(df['Event_Type'] == 'Goal') & (df['Roster_Designation'] == 'Female') & (df['Roster_Designation'].shift() == 'Male') & (df['Event_Type'].shift() == 'Assist')])
male_male = len(df[(df['Event_Type'] == 'Goal') & (df['Roster_Designation'] == 'Male') & (df['Roster_Designation'].shift() == 'Male') & (df['Event_Type'].shift() == 'Assist')])
male_female = len(df[(df['Event_Type'] == 'Goal') & (df['Roster_Designation'] == 'Male') & (df['Roster_Designation'].shift() == 'Female') & (df['Event_Type'].shift() == 'Assist')])

print(f"Female goals assisted by Females: {female_female}")
print(f"Female goals assisted by Males: {female_male}")
print(f"Male goals assisted by Males: {male_male}")
print(f"Male goals assisted by Females: {male_female}")
```

---

```
Output:
Female goals assisted by Females: 1
Female goals assisted by Males: 1
Male goals assisted by Males: 1
Male goals assisted by Females: 1
```

Explanation of var assignment:

We're wrapping everything in a len() so that we are assigning a number as the final value

The 4 conditions we are checking for (female -> male for example) are:

- Is current value for key *Event_Type* == Goal?
- Is current value for key *Roster_Designation* == Female?
- Is the previous value(shift) for key *Roster_Designation* == Male?
- Is the previous value(shift) for key *Event_Type* == assist?

If all above is yes, then count it.

Answer (score 0):

How's this:

```
assister_index = pd.Series(
    df[df["Event_Type"] == "Goal"].index.to_series() - 1,
    index=df.index,
    dtype=pd.Int64Dtype(),
)
assister_index[~assister_index.isin(df.index)] = pd.NA

>>> assister_index
4           <NA>
5              4
12          <NA>
13            12
46          <NA>
207095      <NA>
207108      <NA>
207109    207108
207118      <NA>
207119    207118
dtype: Int64

df["Assister_Gender"] = assister_index.map(
    lambda i: df.loc[i, "Roster_Designation"], na_action="ignore"
) 
>>> df
       Event_Type Roster_Designation Assister_Gender
4          Assist               Male            <NA>
5            Goal             Female            Male
12         Assist             Female            <NA>
13           Goal               Male          Female
46           Goal               Male            <NA>
207095       Goal             Female            <NA>
207108     Assist               Male            <NA>
207109       Goal               Male            Male
207118     Assist             Female            <NA>
207119       Goal             Female          Female
```

Now just count the rows matching your desired conditions, e.g.,

```
(
    (df["Event_Type"] == "Goal")
    & (df["Roster_Designation"] == "Female")
    & (df["Assister_Gender"] == "Male")
).sum()
```

Comment: You're so smart! Thank you!

Comment: @PRuss Not smart, just experienced. If this answers your question, you should accept it as the answer.